# Failed to validate OAuth signature and token twitter integration ios GTM-OAuth

Tags: ios, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using following code to handle twitter integration in my Application.

```
- (IBAction)signInWithTwitter:(id)sender {    
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
NSString *scope = @"http://api.twitter.com/";

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self authForTwitter];
[auth setCallback:@"http://www.noop.com/OAuthCallback"];

GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
viewController = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                             language:nil
                                                      requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                    authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                       accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                       authentication:auth
                                                       appServiceName:@"CK12: Twitter"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
}

- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)authForTwitter {

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                     consumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
                                                      privateKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET];

[auth setServiceProvider:@"Twitter"];

return auth;
}
```

My problem is, if I am changing device time i.e making it 1 hour late, then I am getting following error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 and error message is : failed to validate oauth signature and token .
```

So can anybody please suggest how to solve this. if system time is wrong then also I want to make it work .

Comment: Have u checked your App secret and App secret key

Comment: if system time is correct then this is working fine . . . so app secret and app key are correct .

Comment: twitter server checks the time-stamp of your request ... so u have to send the current time correctly, I think there's no other option.

Comment: @IslamAhmed can we get twitter server time and make changes in code to make timestamp of request correct according to twitter server

Comment: No, but u can search online for a time service api and contact with it to get the current time in GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this . . . .

One of the reason we get this error "Failed to validate OAuth signature and token" 
when system time is wrong . Because OAuth request carry system timestamp parameters with it , so when device time is not within the 5 minutes of twitter server time  .we get "Failed to validate OAuth signature and token" .

There are two ways to make it work , if the device time is even wrong .

1.make HTTP HEAD request to an endpoint on api.twitter.com -- you'll get a Date HTTP header in the response that indicates the current time understood by Twitter. You would then convert this to epoch time and adjust your oauth_timestamp values by a determined offset.

2.There's a small iOS library named ios-ntp link: http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp . use this to get the current Accurate time .

After that i just set the timestamp of OAuth object in the following method

```
- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)authForTwitter 
{
GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] 
            initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
            consumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
            privateKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET];
[auth setServiceProvider:@"Twitter"];     
NSDate * currentdate = //GET ACCURATE DATE HERE ;            
[auth setTimestamp:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[currentdate timeIntervalSince1970]]];
return auth;
}
```

that's it . . .Happy Coding :)